# Force download PHP - not downloading the whole file

Tags: php, download

I have a problem with forcing download of some mp3/zip files.

The problem is that some users experiences that the whole file isn't downloaded, and i can't figure out why..

```
if(is_file($file_name))
{

    /*
        Do any processing you'd like here:
        1.  Increment a counter
        2.  Do something with the DB
        3.  Check user permissions
        4.  Anything you want!
    */

    // required for IE
    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) { ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); }

    // get the file mime type using the file extension
    switch(strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1)))
    {
        case 'mp3': $mime = 'audio/mpeg'; break;
        case 'zip': $mime = 'application/zip'; break;
        default: $mime = 'application/force-download';
    }
    header('Pragma: public');   // required
    header('Expires: 0');       // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($file_name)).' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: private',false);
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));    // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');
    readfile($file_name);       // push it out
    exit();

}
```

here is my code..

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that a partial download is not possible? This is normal if you use readfile.

Comment: so it looks that the download is finished but the file is not complete?

Comment: Does this happen with certain files only? Or is it totally random? What does $file_name output in such an occasion?

Comment: check the file size and max_execution_time directive, maybe on slow connections the script takes too much time to serve the file.

Comment: some users can download 2mb of the file others 25mb, and the file is about 50mb, but the mp3 files are playable, its just not the hole song/mix.

@ Bono - $file_name executes the file name ex. "Kongsted - June Mixtape.mp3"
@ Elzo Valugi - I'll try that...

The funny thing is that when i try and cant get the error the other users experiences :(

Comment: sounds like a max execution time issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your help,

but i found another solution to my problem, and used mod_xsendfile instead. It has done the job for me :)